# How to execute Main-Class as part of compile in SBT

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I wanted to execute a task as part of SBT compile, I tried `runMain in compile` but it is not executing the main class that I am providing. Below is how task looks like in `build.sbt`

```
lazy val scalaGeneratorPlugin =  Project("scala-generator", file("scala-generator"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies += "org.freemarker" % "freemarker" % "2.3.23",
        runMain in compile := Some("com.my.MyMainClass")
  )
```

I am running following command:

```
sbt scala-generator/compile
```

Although it gives me `success` message, it does not execute my MainClass

Comment: To run the main class you need to use `run` task, it will trigger `compile` if needed.

Comment: @laughedelic yeah, but that is not my goal, I want generated compiled `scala` files in the `CLASSPATH` other module so that it can have it during its development/ compilation.

Comment: I think you should use [source generation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) in sbt for that, i.e. there should be different compilation stages.

Comment: Thanks @laughedelic that was helpful. I will try that.

Answer (score -1):

I am copying laughedelic's answer in comment here:

> I think you should use [source generation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html) in sbt for that, i.e. there should be different compilation stages.

Comment: Per community guidelines, answers should not only include a link, but also give a relevant summary of what's included in the link.

Comment: "there should be a different compilation stages" summarizes that needs to be done.